# How long does it take to transfer 1GB via USB2?

Tags: usb, file-transfer

Let’s say you are transferring a 1 GB file from your USB storage device to your computer. You connect your USB storage device to a USB 2.0 port, how long does it take to transfer the files?

Comment: Too long. I'm afraid. :)

Comment: Did you think about simply trying it to find out?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the performance of the USB device, the USB subsystem, the storage system and the computer you're connecting the USB device to. Theoretically USB 2.0 has a bandwidth of 480 Mbit/s, which is about 57 MiB/s. However, due to encoding overhead and inefficiencies in the protocol this speed is not obtainable and ideal conditions would probably yield around 30-40 MiB/s.

Based on this it's guaranteed to take more than 18.5 seconds, half a minute would be fast and if conditions are particularly poor you're still waiting.